# Google Sheets formula to be applied in rows where there is only numbers

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets workbook, have lot of data in it in the following way as shown in the picture:

[image: Sample Sheet]

So What I want to do is to highlight all rows in which **LDCP > Current** (Displayed in green), that is fine when I use conditional formatting and add a formula. But since there are 1000s of such rows, what I want to do is to select all and apply that formula however when I do that it highlights the rows with text such as Leasing Companies and Leather & Tanneries.

Is there a way that I can select the whole sheet and apply a formula which only is applicable where the B column (LDCP) and F Column (Current) consists of numbers. This way only those rows will be highlighted and not the other ones.

Any other kind of advice to do this would be appreciated as well.

Regards,
~K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your conditional formatting custom formula:

`=and($B1>$F1,isnumber($B1))`

Range `A1:Fnnn` where nnn is the end of your sheet.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!